# Where to put code which should run and set up some variables for every route?

Tags: php, symfony, controller, symfony-2.1

I want to run some session handling code every time a URL or route is called, but I obviously want to be able to access this session variable in any controller I wish. Am I wrong in assuming that this should go in the front controller of my bundle?

I tried putting some variables in the `...Bundle.php` file at the root of my bundle's `src`, in `DefaultController.php` (I created a constructor) and more. Nothing works.

#### How can I run some code and set up some variables for every route?

---

Notes:

- I'm new to MVC and Symfony2.
- "every route" == every controller in the bundle I'm talking about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend implementing this as a kernel event listener, and injecting the session into it.

Elaborating:

If you look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html you will see how to register an event listener.

Basically, you use this method to create a kernel event listener that runs every time the system fires up, and also inject the the session (@session in yml) to do what you need to with it.

Comment: For visitors, I had to add the line `arguments: [@session]` after the `class` line in my service definition in `config.yml` (see the link in the answer), and create a constructor for my Listener which takes a `Session` object as a parameter *but does nothing*. Then in my `onKernelRequest` method, I set up my session and can manipulate it there. It can be referenced then in a controller; e.g. if I set a session variable in `onKernelRequest` like `$session->set('a', 'b');` then it's accessible like `$this->get('session')->get('a')`

Answer (score 0):

Look into the kernel event  kernel.request
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#events

If you are not familiar with events look into http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html